# Stop Doctrine from executing an update query if no changes made on the form

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine

I want to stop Doctrine from executing an update query if no changes made on the form.

Does anyone have any idea about that?

Comment: In most cases, this happens automatically: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/change-tracking-policies.html#change-tracking-policies

Comment: @Mohammed: Unless you are playing with RAW SQL or DQL directly, which I assume your are not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It solved by using UnitOfWork outside of listeners like this code

```
$uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
$uow->computeChangeSets();
$changeset = $uow->getEntityChangeSet($user);
if(!empty($changeset)) {
   // my edit code here
}
```